# Spark Streaming and High Availability

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, high-availability

I'm building Apache Spark application that acts on multiple streams.

I did read the Performance Tuning section of the documentation:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning

What I didn't get is:

1) Are the streaming receivers located on multiple worker nodes or is the driver machine?

2) What happens if one of the nodes that receives the data fails (power off/restart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the streaming receivers located on multiple worker nodes or is the
>   driver machine

Receivers are located on *worker* nodes, which are responsible for the consumption of the source which holds the data.

> What happens if one of the nodes that receives the data fails (power
>   off/restart)

The receiver is located on the worker node. The worker node get's it's tasks from the driver. This driver can either be located on a dedicated master server if you're running in Client Mode, or it can be on one of the workers if you're running in Cluster Mode. In case a node fails which doesn't run the driver, the driver will re-assign the partitions held on the failed node to a different one, which will then be able to re-read the data from the source, and do the additional processing needed to recover from the failure.

This is why a replayable source such as Kafka or AWS Kinesis is needed.

Comment: Ok, so if the worker with receiver will be killed - the driver will re-instantiate the receiver and new worker will start receiving the data again - all this automatically. It sounds reasonable, but is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @PiotrR I think you're [looking for this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics)